# Check If N == M*2 in the array

Tags: php

I'm starting solving problem on leetcode, this problem didn't pass the test cases, this my try:

```
function checkIfExist($arr) {
    
    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    $n = count($arr);
    
    // loop over the array
    for($i; $i < $n; $i++) {
        for($j; $j < $n; $j++) {    
            // check if element of i and j not the same and N*2 = M
            if ($i != $j && $arr[$i] * 2 == $arr[$j]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Can please explain to me where I did the error here?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is the function did not pass the test cases..

Comment: What's the problem you are solving from leetcode? You may add it to your question, a link at least.

Comment: I tried to respect the norms of asking question that's why, by the way the problem is "Check If N and Its Double Exist"

Comment: Please add some example input and the expected output.

Comment: This is the link of the problem, you can check it out.. https://leetcode.com/problems/check-if-n-and-its-double-exist/

Comment: How do you call the function? (or in other words, what is `$arr` exactly?)

Comment: The problem is `$j` is not initialized in the for-loop. The norms of asking question on this site is here: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you need explain your title in the question.

Comment: Thank you you sign helpt me I will post the answer after while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initializing of $j and $i pointer inside the for-loop done the work

```
 function checkIfExist($arr) {
    
        $n = count($arr);
    
        // loop over the array
        for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
            for($j = 0; $j < $n; $j++) {    
                // check if element of i and j not the same and N*2 = M
                if ($i != $j && $arr[$i] * 2 == $arr[$j]) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, try this though (it's like one of the sort algorithms). That is weird because only difference is the initialization of the `$i` and `$j`

```php
function checkIfExist($arr) {
    
    $n = count($arr);
    
    // loop over the array
    for($i = 0; $i < $n - 1; $i++) {
        for($j = $i + 1; $j < $n; $j++) {    
            // check if element of i and j not the same and N*2 = M
            if ($i != $j && $arr[$i] * 2 == $arr[$j]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's strang, your changes also didn't work.

Comment: I initialize $j and $i inside the for loop with 0

Comment: no, my changes are working